Can infinite amount of charge be stored inside a conductor placed in vacuum?
I am currently studying about capacitance and got to know that a metal plates system kept in some medium can store a finite amount of charge as per its capacitance, because after storing a certain amount of charge the stretching force on nearby medium particles increases to the extent that dielectric breakdown takes place and we say charges start leaking from the metal.
Then what about a metal plate kept in vacuum with no particles? Can we store infinite amount of charge in it?

No because field electron emission will happen if the voltage is high enough.
